# Wordpress Template not getting my Sub-Header File

Tags: headers

My template works fine, however, its using my main header file, even though I have changed it to point to `sub-header.php`

```
<?php /* Template Name: Sub Page */ 
get_header('sub-header'); ?>
```

Comment: See [developers w.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/) and `$templates[] = "header-{$name}.php";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are following a wrong format to call sub header file.

**Here is how we have to call sub header files:**

```
<?php get_header('subexample'); ?>
```

**Here is how you have to name the sub header file:**

`header-subexample.php`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to pass the slug to get_header() function;
 for example, to call header-sample.php:

```
<?php get_header( 'sample' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you header file name

From `sub-header.php` to `header-sub.php`  and call it by using following code:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Sub Page */ 
get_header('sub'); ?>
```

[For more detail see here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header)

Answer (score 0):

When using the `get_header()` function, all you need to do is name the file as like

`header-sub-header.php` or `header-content.php`.

When you are using the `get_header()` function you would call the your custom headers like this:

```
get_header( "sub-header" )
//OR
get_header ( "content" )
```